# 3D Graph plotting for C++

Tags: c++, linux, charts, graph, plot

I need to plot my simulation (which I do in a C++ application) for use in a Latex document (so I would prefer some vector output like EPS). My function is of 2 arguments, so I am after a 3D plot, ideally with colouring indicating the function value (similar to what Mathematica does). Could anyone recommend any library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)? I use it for this sort of thing. If you really need a library, then I'd look at [gnuplot++](http://www.suiri.tsukuba.ac.jp/~asanuma/gnuplot++/)

Answer (score 3):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) have large set of 1D (curves), 2D (surfaces) and 3D (volume) plot types. It also have export to EPS and parse some of TeX formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at QwtPlot3d (http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/), if you can use Qt in your project.
(Basically it is OpenGL rendering library, but AFAIK it has ability to produce EPS output)

PS.I had never used it, but have experience in QwtPlot (related 2d ploting library), and it is pretty well designed and flexible library.

Edit:
From features list of this library:
"..."
"- Vector output (PostScript,  EPS and PDF)  via gl2ps"
"..."